# API Demo video stream not working

Tags: java, android, video-streaming

The Api Demo asks to edit the path to stream video from the net. I edited it as shown below with a path which was suggested on the blog to fix the problem, but it didn't work and came up with error (1, -1004). I couldn't find any other answer, any ideas? I am using Galaxy S 2.3.3

```
case STREAM_VIDEO:
   /*
    * TODO: Set path variable to progressive streamable mp4 or
    * 3gpp format URL. Http protocol should be used.
    * Mediaplayer can only play "progressive streamable
    * contents" which basically means: 1. the movie atom has to
    * precede all the media data atoms. 2. The clip has to be
    * reasonably interleaved.
    * 
    */
    path = "http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp";
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.